# dynamic Layout; viewBag vs render actions

Tags: design, web-development, asp.net-mvc

I am a intern student working on a project. We have the need to use a dynamic layout. Originally all that we needed was to know whether or not a search input should appear in the navbar and what catalog that should search on. Now there is more meta-info needed about the search and other dynamically displayed side bars.

All this information can be retrieved from contexts available in every page request so I was overriding the `OnActionExecuted` method in the projects `baseController` it looked some what like this.

```
    OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var controllerName = context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
        this.ViewBag.Things = getStuff(controllerName);
        this.ViewBag.OtherThings = getMoreStuff(contollerName);
        //.... about 15 more ViewBag variables....
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
```

Now in my layout, and any other page I can use all of these things. problem is the `ViewBag` is quickly becoming bloated, and I'm sure they will find more dynamic things to put in the layout. Also this seems to be promoting a somewhat ad-hoc approach that I'm not entirely comfortable with.

Instead I think I will move to using `renderAction` in the layout for these dynamic parts and forgo most of the `ViewBag` properties. Is there a major downside to using `renderAction` that I am not aware of? Am I over engineering and it is fine to stick with the `ViewBag` heavy approach?

I tried pushing back on having such a dynamic layout because it seems like a weird design choice but they insist on having it, so I am curious as to best approach to such a thing. My current approach is working but seems bad for maintainability and growth of the site.

Answer (score 1):

If every view needs common data, create a child class of System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage that has the common stuff for each page:

```
public abstract class BasePageView<T> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<T>
{
    // the common stuff goes here
}
```

And then use it in your Razor Views:

```
@inherits BasePageView<YourViewModel>

@this.CommonThing1.Foo()
```

Comment: Not every view needs common data. This layout needs common data. We have a few different layouts being used. student teacher admin etc.... The question is since there are a lot of variables needed should we create actions and call render action in the layout or is it acceptable to just pack a ton of `ViewBag` properties to be used in the layout. Thank you for the response, but I don't think this answer is appropriate for this situation.